# How to store data in a class that contains three data variable in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have class "Button," that is a subclass of CCNode. Since a button (as in computer buttons), IS-NOT a CCLabelBMFont or CCSprite, I subclassed it as a CCNode. In addition, I have extended CCLabelBMFont with child "CCLabelCustom" that has some fancy logic of its own. With that, I have moved CCLabelCustom *buttonLabel and CCSprite *buttonSprite as an iVar of "Button." I want "Button" to be as abstract as possible, with no default buttonLabel or buttonSprite. The thing is, how do I go initing both CCLabelCustom and CCSprite? The CCLabelCustom have some long inits with more than four parameter and additional properties can be assigned.

```
// Rough Idea to help elaborate my classes
@interface Button : CCNode

@property (nonatomic, strong) CCLabelCustom *buttonLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite *buttonSprite;

@end


// Rough Idea to help elaborate my classes
@interface CCLabelCustom : CCLabelBMFont

@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeProperty *someVar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AnotherProperty *anotherVar;

-(void)fancyMethod;
-(void)initWithSomething:(Something*)something andAnother:(Another*)another alongWith:(Fun*)fun;

@end
```

Is there any architecture that I don't know of? Is there any method that I can init "Button" with the two iVar from outside the class? I don't want any default value that I can define inside the "Button" class. I want to do it from a outside layer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. What is the objective of your software design? Cannot you keep the buttonLabel and buttonSprite initialized to `nil` in the designated Button init method, and then populate them according in specific init methods for each of the "subtypes" of your class?

Comment: That's the thing. I don't what to have a specific instance of my iVar inside the Button init. I want to be as abstract as possible. I want to reuse the button class with different CCSprites and CCLabelCustom every time I use a Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the method `initWithSomething:(Something*)something andAnother:(Another*)another alongWith:(Fun*)fun;` on your `Button` class. And on this init of your `Button`, also init the 
`CCLabelCustom` with these parameters.

Then when you will init your button outside the class, use this method and pass the parameters.

PS.: The method `initWithSomething` must return an ID object: `-(id)initWithSomething:`

Example:

```
// Outside class
Button *button = [[Button alloc] initWithSomething:something andAnother:another alongWith:fun];

...
// Your Button custom init
- (id)initWithSomething:(Something*)something andAnother:(Another*)another alongWith:(Fun*)fun
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        self.buttonLabel = [[CCLabelCustom alloc] initWithSomething:something andAnother:another alongWith:fun]
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have thought of this approach, but this lead to even more questions. How will I go about change someVar and anotherVar inside Button? I remember reading somewhere that constantly using something like "someButton.buttonLabel.someVar = someVarLocal" is bad practice? Also, how will I init buttonSprite with this newly made init? *Passed character Limit so please continue to second post for more info*

Comment: Is it bad practice to do something like -(id)initWithLabel:(CCLabelCustom*)label sprite:(CCSprite*)sprite; and call something like this from a outside class: self.button = [[Button alloc] initWithLabel:[CCLabelCustom initWithSomething:something andAnother:another alongWith:fun] sprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite.png"]]; and later assigning a property like this: button.buttonLabel.someVar = xxx;

Comment: Almost all Cocos2d objects use this 'initWithSomething' (and also an static constructor like 'buttonWithSomething', that will call 'initWithSomething' and return a autorelease object). If you dont want that outside class access button properties directly, create a method on button that do this. Example: Button method setLabelText:, that will change the itself property buttonLabel.string

Comment: Thank you again for the answer. But is accessing button's properties bad practice? I don't mind an outside class accessing buttonSprite or buttonLabel, but I don't want raise a red card if I do so. I know it's common in Cocos2D to have something like "initWithSomething," but is it normal to init CCSprite and CCLabelCustom and passed it down to Button like that?

Comment: It isn't a bad practice, but creating methods to change Button properties is the recommended approach. This way you can prevent outside class to do some wrong things with Button's properties, like remove then from parentNode.